# Check if power network is up, having my circuit powered via UPS

Tags: arduino, circuit-analysis, sensor, circuit-design

I have this circuit bellow in the image, I want to monitor if there is power in the room. I have arduino mega powered by a UPS, so if there is no power in the network, the sensoring will still continue for some time. The PN 5V pins are 5V taken by a 'power supply' a normal 5V phone charger, plugged not in UPS but straight to a plug. I use this resistor voltage divider, provide ~3.2V. Is this circuit viable or alterations are necessary?[image]
The thought is that if there is power in PN pin there will be 5V translated to 3.3V, if there is no power there will 0V so arduino will perceive it as logical 0.

Answer (score 0):

No, this will not work, if the PN connections are coming from a separate 5v phone charger / power supply. Its output is isolated from the Arduino ground, so the voltage of pin D8 will be indeterminate. The series resistors will likely protect it from damage (if you've already tried this), but you will probably be seeing a mains frequency leakage signal there.

If you connect the PN GND to the Arduino GND, then it will work as you want.